# Passing config properties to controllers

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin

I'm self-hosting Owin in a Windows service that provides some functionality and access to other Windows for other functionalities. I have a provider that's starting the Owin app and is also the entry point to all of the system's functionalities.

How can I pass a reference to my provider to each of the controllers? The ApiController class provides Configuration.Properies, but I can't find a way to add the provider reference to the configuration properties. The StartOptions class has Settings, but it only takes string values. I also don't see a way to pass an extra parameter to the Startup class' Configuration method.

```
public class Provider : BaseProvider
{
   public override void StartUp()
   {
      var options = new StartOptions();
      //StartOptions.Settings only allows string values
      //I need to pass this provider to the controllers

      WebApp.Start<StartUp>("http://SVS:1234");
   }
}

internal class StartUp
{
    private Provider _provider = null;

    internal void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "POSEngineAPI",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

        //??? How can I set _provider when calling Startup.Config?
        config.Properties.AddOrUpdate("Provider", _provider, (key, value) => _provider);

        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}

internal class SessionController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult PostSession(Session session)
    {
        var provider = GetProvider();
        //TODO
        return Ok(session);
    }

    [HttpPut]
    public IHttpActionResult PutSession(Session session)
    {
        var provider = GetProvider();
        //TODO
        return Ok(session);
    }

    private WebApiSignalRProvider GetProvider()
    {
        return Configuration.Properties["Provider"] as Provider;
    }
}
```

I'm new to Web Api and Owin so I'm probably missing something obvious.

Comment: Why do you need a reference to web app runner class in the controllers of web application which is started by this runner?

Comment: The provider is essentially an adapter that converts the client communications to the WCF communications used by our services. The PutSession implementation will be something like 'return Ok(provider.OpenSession(session)'.

Comment: I now understand that app.UseWebApi isn't just initializing an in-memory component -- it's actually starting up a separate app domain so it makes sense that you can't just pass in a reference. I'll have to take a couple of steps back and rethink this part of our design.